# C#.net 4.5+ getting full enclosing type namespaces and properties

Tags: c#, .net

Given the class definitions below, is there any way to walk up the caller tree to retrieve the enclosing namespaces and property names:

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public class A
    {
        public B ChildModel { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Namespace2
{
    public class B
    {
        public B()
        {
            this.SubChild = new C();
            this.SecondSubChild = new C();
        }
        public C SubChild { get; set; }
        public C SecondSubChild { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Namespace3
{
    public class C
    {
        public C()
        {
            // When SubChild gets initialized above it should output Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SubChild.Namespace3.C
            // When SecondSubChild gets initialized above it should output Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SecondSubChild.Namespace3.C
            Console.WriteLine("...");
        }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And instantiating class A like so would output all the enclosing namespaces, types and property names in C's constructor:

```
var model = new A { ChildModel = new B() };
```

I tried using StackTrace which will return the namespace and class names, however I was not able to get the property names, and the other problem I had was that class A was not part of the stack frames since it doesn't have an explicit constructor. I would also like to avoid using reflection if possible.

UPDATE:
What I am trying to achieve is to encrypt the Name property in my C class, however when encrypting I want to make sure that another property of type C defined in another class or with a different name uses a different encryption key. For instance, when C gets instantiated from class B.SubChild it will encrypt using "Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SubChild.Namespace3.C" as its key, whereas when calling the C constructor from B.SecondSubChild it will use Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SecondSubChild.Namespace3.C.

Thanks!

Comment: "I would also like to avoid using reflection if possible." - so, you want to inspect the metadata of your code without using the technology that inspects the metadata of your code? Not sure you'll be able to do it *without* reflection, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of avoiding it by walking up the class/ namespace structure at compile time and storing that somehow.

Comment: Objects are constructed before they're assigned, so you won't be able to fetch the 'destinations' of your objects from the stacktrace. So even reflection probably won't be enough to achieve exactly what you want -  it looks like the only way to do this is to actually inspect IL bytecode at runtime. What do you intend to use this for?

Comment: Your code will not be compiled. You'll need to clarify in class A to which namespace class B belongs. The same about class C. You'll need to add reference to namespace. Maybe you can edit your question to make it correct from viewpoint of C# compiler?

Comment: Hey Peter, I have updated my question with what I am trying to do: What I am trying to achieve is to encrypt the Name property in my C class, however when encrypting I want to make sure that another property of type C defined in another class or with a different name uses a different encryption key. For instance, when C gets instantiated from class B.SubChild it will encrypt using "Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SubChild.Namespace3.C" as its key, whereas when calling the C constructor from B.SecondSubChild it will use Namespace1.A.ChildModel.Namespace2.B.SecondSubChild.Namespace3.C.

Comment: Then why don't you just pass the encryption key as an argument to `C`'s constructor?

Comment: I could, but I didn't necessarily want to force it to where B in this case has a constructor necessarily, or even C for that matter because I may also have a property of type C in A which in this case does not have a constructor.

Comment: You can provide multiple constructor overloads or make the encryption key argument optional, and only apply encryption if an encryption key is provided.

Comment: That is true, however then I would have encryption keys that I would need to define all over the app which may be a little messy and hard to maintain whereas if I could get the exact nested structure via code I wouldn't have to worry about it.